# Input file doesn't exist even though the file is mentioned in the correct location- pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read log lines by forming key-value pairs but I get an error.
This is my code:

```
logLine=sc.textFile("C:\TestLogs\testing.log").cache() 
lines = logLine.flatMap(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
rx = "(\\S+)=(\\S+)" 
line_collect = lines.collect() 
for line in line_collect :  
    d = dict([(x,y) for x,y in re.findall(rx,line)])    
    d = str(d)  
    print d
```

Error:

> line_collect = lines.collect()......InvalidInputException: Input path
>   does not exist: file:/C:/TestLogs  esting.log

I don't know how to correct this. I'm new to python and spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace `logLine=sc.textFile("C:\TestLogs\testing.log").cache()` with 
`logLine=sc.textFile("C:\\TestLogs\\testing.log").cache()`

The backslash character is not `'\'` in a string but rather `"\\"`

Answer (score 2):

When the character sequence `\t` is found in a string, it will be replaced by a TAB character. You can actually see this in the error message.

I'd recommend always using the forward slash `/` as the directory separator, even on Windows. Alternatively prefix the string with an r like this: `r"does not replace \t with <tab>."`.

You might want to read up on string literals: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html.